# PayPal REST API returning 500-Error when trying to create payment-object

Tags: javascript, typescript, curl, paypal, xmlhttprequest

I try to integrate the PayPal PLUS API into my NativeScript Mobile App. When creating a payment (calling this API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#create_payment) with the shortened call displayed on the side I keep getting a 500-Error. Sadly I did not find out how to display the message of it.

I am running my code on an iOS Emulator (Xcode 7) via NativeScript.

I tried the following curl-call, which worked for me:

What I tried with curl:

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <my-token>„ \
-d '{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
      "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
  {
      "amount": {
      "total": "30.11",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "details": {
          "subtotal": "30.00",
          "tax": "0.07",
          "shipping": "0.03",
          "handling_fee": "1.00",
          "shipping_discount": "-1.00",
          "insurance": "0.01"
      }
  },
  "item_list": {
      "items": [
      {
          "name": "hat",
          "description": "Brown hat.",
          "quantity": "5",
          "price": "3",
          "tax": "0.01",
          "sku": "1",
          "currency": "EUR"
      },
      {
          "name": "handbag",
          "description": "Black handbag.",
          "quantity": "1",
          "price": "15",
          "tax": "0.02",
          "sku": "product34",
          "currency": "EUR"
      }
    ]}
  }
  ],
  "redirect_urls": {
  "return_url": "http://www.paypal.com/return",
  "cancel_url": "http://www.paypal.com/cancel"
  }
}'
```

responding a 201-Created response.

Now I created an XHR-Object in TypeScript with the same elements. My code so far:

```
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    oReq.open("POST", PayPalEndpoints.getPaymentEndpoint, true);
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + access_token);
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json");
    oReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log("state changed - new state: " + oReq.readyState + " and Status: " + oReq.status);
        if (oReq.readyState === 4) {     
            if (oReq.status === 200) {        
                var response = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);          
                console.log("response = " + response);
            } else { 
                console.log("Error: " + oReq.status + " Message: " + oReq.responseText);
            } 
        }    
    };

    oReq.send({
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "transactions": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "total": "30.11",
                "currency": "EUR",
                "details": {
                "subtotal": "30.00",
                "tax": "0.07",
                "shipping": "0.03",
                "handling_fee": "1.00",
                "shipping_discount": "-1.00",
                "insurance": "0.01"
            }
            },
            "item_list": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "name": "hat",
                        "description": "Brown hat.",
                        "quantity": "5",
                        "price": "3",
                        "tax": "0.01",
                        "sku": "1",
                        "currency": "EUR"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "handbag",
                        "description": "Black handbag.",
                        "quantity": "1",
                        "price": "15",
                        "tax": "0.02",
                        "sku": "product34",
                        "currency": "EUR"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
        ],
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url":"http://www.paypal.com/return",
            "cancel_url":"http://www.paypal.com/cancel"
        }
    });
```

which is (like mentioned above) not working for me. Does someone know, how to display the error message from that XHR-Object? Or maybe someone even sees what might be wrong with my code. If you need an API call that worked (via XHR):

```
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    var encodedString = base64.encode(this.authorizationBasic);
    oReq.open("POST", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", false);
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Basic " +  encodedString);

    oReq.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json");
    oReq.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language', "en_US");

    oReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log("state changed - new state: " + oReq.readyState + " and Status: " + oReq.status);
        if (oReq.readyState === 4) {
            if (oReq.status === 200) {        
                var response = JSON.parse(oReq.responseText);          
                OAuthAccessor.access_token = response.access_token;
                console.log("access_token set");
            } else { 
                console.log("Error: " + oReq.status + " Message: " + oReq.responseText);
            } 
        }    
    };

    oReq.send('grant_type=client_credentials');
```

API reference:

Integration pdf:
https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/de_DE/downloads/PayPal-PLUS-IntegrationGuide.pdf

Call reference:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/

The call I shortened:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#create_payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is doing research on an equal problem:

You need to change the

```
 oReq.setRequestHeader('Accept', "application/json");
```

to

```
oReq.setRequestHeader('Grant-Type', "application/json");
```

and you need to pass the data in the send-Method as a json-string, so call:

```
 oReq.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

with "data" being your JSON String.